# JPG Processing steps compression Decompression

Tags: c#, image-processing, jpeg

kindly, i need your support to help me to complete processing steps to compression\Decompression JPG Image.

i have complete do below steps:

1- convert Image from RGB range to YCbCr...

2- split Image into block 8X8.

3- Subtract each pixel with 128.

4- apply FDCT on each block.

5- apply ZegZag on each block.

6- apply RLC on it...

here questions : 
what next step ? 
how can combine blocks after splitting? 
any source code or any thing ???

thanks ... :)

Comment: to complete steps read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83225/A-Simple-JPEG-Encoder-in-C

Comment: thanks i was reed it but not found my request also it is not working successfuly...

Answer (score 0):

> 1- convert Image from RGB range to YCbCr...

After that comes subsampling

> 2- split Image into block 8X8.

Unless you count subsampling as part of this step

> 3- Subtract each pixel with 128.
>
> 4- apply FDCT on each block.

Then you have to do quantization.

> 5- apply ZegZag on each block.
>
> 6- apply RLC on it...

In reality, 5 and 6 are the same steps.  If you want optimized huffman codes you have to make two passes here. Pass 1 gets the counts and Pass 2 does the huffman coding. Then you'd have the additional step in between of generating the huffman table.

That that you write the RLE MCU's to the output stream. You may have to insert restart markers.

All of this assumes you are using sequential JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

The first code in each 8 x 8 block is the Dc term and uses different huffmand tables.  This first dc term must be saved as it is added to the next block.
Also 8 x 8 blocks must be quantized which is simpley multiplying by a block of 8 x 8 constants.  The quantization tables are stored in the compressed Jpeg file.
There is a free library for the Independent Jpeg Group available with source.